# Trying to demonstrate polymorphism, but can't get my methods to accept my ArrayLists

Tags: polymorphism

I am running into an error on my last two lines trying to call the method from my Math class. The error is saying "The method computeAverage(int[]) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)".

I'm not sure why I'm running into this problem.

Here is my Math Class:

```
public class Math {

 public static double computeAverage(int[] numbers) {
    int sum=0;
    for( int i=0 ; i<numbers.length ; i++){ 
        sum+=numbers[i];}
    return (sum/numbers.length);


    } 
 public static double computeAverage(double[] numbers) {
     double sum=0;
        for( int i=0 ; i<numbers.length ; i++){ 
            sum+=numbers[i];}
        return (sum/numbers.length);
        }
 }
```

Here is my Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Number> d = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList();

     d.add(1);
     d.add(2);
     d.add(3);
     d.add(16);
     d.add(20);
     d.add(100);

     numbers.add(21.7);
     numbers.add(37.5);
     numbers.add(6.3);

     Math.computeAverage(d);
     Math.computeAverage(numbers);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int[]` and `double[]` are primitive arrays, they aren't directly compatible with collection classes such as `ArrayList`.

Since you mentioned polymorphism, I believe what you're trying to do is have a single method that can work on both `int`s and `double`s. The setup in your `main` method is good for that: you are already able to add both int and double values into `ArrayList<Number>` since `Number` is a superclass of both `Integer` and `Double`.

What you need to change is the `computeAverage` method. You don't need two copies, you just need one that takes a `List<Number>`, which will be able to work with any kind of number:

```
public static double computeAverage(List<Number> numbers) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (Number n : numbers) {
    sum += n.doubleValue();
  }
  return sum / n.size();
}
```